# Convert mutliple columns of dataFrame to a dictionary and store in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am new to Pandas, and trying to achieve the following:
I have a data Frame that looks like this:

```
                   Country     Capital        Area  Population

0                  Russia        Moscow         6601670   146171015

1                  Canada       Ottawa         3855100    38048738

2                  China        Beijing         3705407  1400050000
```

How do I convert it to a data Frame that looks like:

```
                    Country       Details 

0                    Russia       {Capital: Moscow, Area:6601670, Population: 146171015}

1                    Canada       {Capital: Ottawa, Area:3855100, Population: 38048738}

2                     China       {Capital: Ottawa, Area:3705407, Population: 1400050000}
```

I want to delete columns from the original data Frame, and store them as a dictionary in a new column in the same data frame

Comment: Did you try anything yet?  Pandas has something called `to_dict` you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [32]: # set a default value for the new column "Details"

In [33]: df['Details'] = None

In [34]: # create an empty list called details

In [35]: details = []

In [36]: # then iterate over the rows

In [37]: for index, row in df.iterrows():
    ...:     details.append({'Capital': row.Capital, 'Area': row.Area, 'Population'
    ...: : row.Population})
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: 

In [38]: # now you have all the details

In [48]: df.drop(['Capital', 'Area', 'Population'], axis=1, inplace=True)

In [49]: df
Out[49]: 
  Country                                            Details
0  Russia  {'Capital': 'Moscow', 'Area': 6601670, 'Popula...
1  Canada  {'Capital': 'Ottawa', 'Area': 3855100, 'Popula...
2   China  {'Capital': 'Beijing', 'Area': 3705407, 'Popul...

In [50]: # VOILA!

In [51]:
```